# HTML how to clear input using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, erase

I have this INPUT, it will clear everytime we click inside of it.

The problem:
I want to clear only if value = exemplo@exemplo.com

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearThis(target) {
        target.value= "";
    }
</script>
<input type="text" name="email" value="exemplo@exemplo.com" size="30" onfocus="clearThis(this)">
```

Can someone help me to do this?
I don't know how to compare, I already tried but no success.

Comment: You're looking for the `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: IE8 does not inherently support `placeholder` attribute

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearThis(target) {
        if (target.value == 'exemplo@exemplo.com') {
            target.value = "";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is this really what your looking for?

Answer (score 18):

For me this is the best way:

```html
<form id="myForm">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Demo"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">
</form>
     
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, consider adding an explanation of why you think this would be a solution to OP's question as it is concerned with resetting the input value under a specific condition. This is especially important since other answers already cover the question. Do take a look at answering [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 4):

you can use attribute `placeholder`

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="exemplo@exemplo.com" size="30" />
```

or try this for older browsers

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="exemplo@exemplo.com" size="30" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='exemplo@exemplo.com';}" onfocus="if(this.value=='exemplo@exemplo.com'){this.value='';}">
```

Comment: And what about IE 9 and older?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a placeholder because it does it for you, but for old browsers that don't support placeholder, try this:

```
<script>
function clearThis(target) {
    if (target.value == "exemplo@exemplo.com") {
        target.value = "";
    }
}
function replace(target) {
    if (target.value == "" || target.value == null) {
        target.value == "exemplo@exemplo.com";
    }
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="email" value="exemplo@exemplo.com" size="x" onfocus="clearThis(this)" onblur="replace(this)" />
```

CODE EXPLAINED: When the text box has focus, clear the value. When text box is not focused AND when the box is blank, replace the value.

I hope that works, I have been having the same issue, but then I tried this and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clearThis(target){
    if(target.value == "exemplo@exemplo.com")
    {
        target.value= "";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearThis(target){
        if (target.value === "exemplo@exemplo.com") {
            target.value= "";
        }
    }
    </script>
<input type="text" name="email" value="exemplo@exemplo.com" size="30" onfocus="clearThis(this)">
```

Try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/2K3Vp/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bother with that. Just write

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="exemplo@exemplo.com" size="30">
```

replace the value with placeholder

Answer (score 0):

instead of clearing the name text use **placeholder** attribute it is good practice

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name"  name="name">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised out of all these answers, no one has mentioned the simplest, most modern way to do this:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Your Name" 
    onfocus="this.placeholder=''" 
    onblur="this.placeholder='Your Name'"
>
```

The `onblur` is only necessary if you want to restore the original placeholder after the user clicks away from the input.