# How do I remove the input typed in by user in an input tag after form submission through vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

```html
 <input type="number" class="setter" id="day-set" name="day-set" value="day"max="30" min="0" placeholder="00"onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>30){ this.value =30; return false;}">
```

How do I make it so that the input typed in by the user in the input field is cleared when a submit button is pressed (the one which does not refreshes the page)

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237772/html-how-to-clear-input-using-javascript

Comment: set a callback function on your button that triggers a reset of the input value.

Answer (score 1):

you can add this to the onclick function of your button and replace the `myForm` with the id of your form element

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and add it into the onSubmit event of your form (assuming that you have a form) and then inside of that function you only need to clear the value using something like this:

```
document.getElementById('day-set').value = ''
```

Example:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
   <input type="number" class="setter" id="day-set" name="day-set" value="day"max="30" min="0" placeholder="00"onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>30){ this.value =30; return false;}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
 function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById('day-set').value = ''
 } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <html>
    <body>
    
      <p>Clear the input field when you click on the button:</p>
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''">Clear input 
       field</button>
    
      <input type="text" value="Blabla" id="myInput">
    
    </body>
   </html>
```

You can also write the javaScript in-between the script tag in a Function or any other way that you want.